Conditionally including a system library (FFmpeg) in Swift Package Manager builds?
I’m working on a Swift project and would like to create two builds of my package:

A basic version without the external C library (FFmpeg).
And a version that includes an optional dependency on FFmpeg.

Here’s what I have so far is two separate Package.swift files:
    ...
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "macSubtitleOCR",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "ArgumentParser", package: "swift-argument-parser")
            ]),
    ...

and:
    ...
    targets: [
        .systemLibrary(
            name: "CFFmpeg",
            pkgConfig: "libavformat libavcodec libavutil",
            providers: [
                .brew(["ffmpeg"])
            ]),
        .executableTarget(
            name: "macSubtitleOCR",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "ArgumentParser", package: "swift-argument-parser"),
                "CFFmpeg"
            ]),
     ...

I've tried adding compile flags like #if FFMPEG and then running swift build -Xswiftc -DFFMPEG which works for the source files, but compile flags don't work properly, and understandably so, in Package.swift.
My question is:

How can I conditionally include a system library like FFmpeg in Package.swift based on build flags or any other approach?
Is using multiple Package.swift files (one with and one without FFmpeg) a reasonable approach, or is there a more correct way to handle optional dependencies in SwiftPM?

I’m relatively new to Swift development, so any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
